# File extension xls but file contain XML data how can read this type of file using PHP

Tags: php

I am working on import and export type project where multiple type of import on daily basis, currently i face some problem to import XLS file data. 
    file extension XLS but data contain in form of XML please advice me
       $path = $dir.$file_name;
       $sheet_data = simplexml_load_file($path); 
       print_r($sheet_data);
       after the print data i can get result like

```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
  (
    [Worksheet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
          [Table] => SimpleXMLElement Object
           (
              [Column] => Array
               (
                  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                   (
                    )

                 [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

           [Row] => Array
                     (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                         (
                         )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                         (
                           [Cell] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                             [Data] => Unavailable Power Generation Capacity in PDBF (MW). Date 10-02-2016
                               )
                            )

                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                         (
                         )

                        )

                )

        )

)

I got file from following URL


    enter code here

http://www.esios.ree.es/Solicitar/salidatotalindisppdbf_20160203.xls&en
```

Comment: It's probably easier if you show the actual XML rather than dump the SimpleXML object; but my guess would be SpreadsheetML

Comment: But how would you read it if it was an xls file? Perhaps the library that you use to read BIFF-format xls files also has options to read SpreadsheetML format files

Comment: $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
 for ($row = 2; $row < 12; $row++) {
 $rowData[$row] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' .    $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
  foreach ($rowData[$row] as $data1);                                                              }  I  Use above code for reading XLS but i got error like OLE not supported.

Comment: So you're using PHPExcel..... it would have helped if you'd said that in the first place..... step #1 should have been to read the PHPExcel documentation, particularly the document entitled [Reading Spreadsheet Files](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files)

Comment: Step #2 is to stop assuming that a file with an xls extension is a real BIFF-format Excel file...... it should be, but lots of people are lazy and give csv files or html files an xls extension and pretend that it's somehow automagically converted into a real xls file.... explicitly telling PHPExcel to use the `Excel5` Reader is falling into this trap.... unless you know that the file really is BIFF format, then don't simply assume that it is just because it has an xls extension

Comment: Step #3 is to use PHPExcel's IOFactory methods like `load()` (which will identify the appropriate Reader to use and load the file accordingly), or `identify()` (which will tell you which Reader you should be using)

Comment: sorry i did not understand this problem i will try last four days, bur i am unable to fix this issue, please  help for any complete example  ?

Comment: Start by reading the [Reading Spreadsheet Files](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files) PHPExcel document that I linked earlier.... that explains about the different filetypes that PHPExcel can read, and how to use the library to read them, and how to use the `load()` and `identify()` methods that I've mentioned

Comment: Basically, if you read that document, it tells you to do `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);` instead of `$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5'); $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);`, as do most of the code examples provided with the library